# The use of CSS zoom:1

Tags: css

I see that the css property `zoom: 1` is often used in stylesheets.
For example twitter bootstrap uses it in its fluid layout:

```
.row-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

I know that it is primarily used for IE layout issues...

What is it actually used for and why? Is it only necessary to use it for fluid layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

in IE, some elements have no layout - which results in huge PITA in designing - so there are many non-intrusive ways to give them 'layout'. `zoom: 1` is one of them.

Comment: thank you. can you be more descriptive? what do you mean by no layout? no set dimensions such as width and height? what would be the result of that?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden see the duplicate